# Amazon SES invalid signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, lua, cryptography, amazon-ses

I am trying to write a little library to get the basic functionality of interacting with the Amazon SES API but I am continuing to run into the same issue:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

I've poured over the docs numerous times over the past few days and I just can't figure out where I am going wrong in my code, and Amazon's error messages don't give me much to work with. Would be nice if there were a debug/test API that would send back detailed info, but to my knowledge there is not.

As far as I can see, I am constructing the canonical messages the way that Amazon requires, I am hashing things in the same ways that Amazon requires, etc. I'm most certain that I'm missing some small detail that would throw the whole thing off. If someone would be able to help me spot that, I'd greatly appreciate it. :)

Code: https://hastebin.com/mezugukefu.lua

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the Amazon SES documentation examples use a consistent, known set of example keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082504/do-the-amazon-ses-documentation-examples-use-a-consistent-known-set-of-example)

Comment: Have you checked that you use the correct encoding (e.g. UTF-8)? Signatures are created on bytes not on characters, hence for signing a string it has to be converted to bytes and each encoding my create a different byte sequence for the same string. Hence if the signature has been created using the "wrong" encoding verification on Amazon side is likely to fail.

Comment: @exnihilo that was also my question :P

Comment: @Robert I believe LuaJIT (which I am using) only natively supports ASCII and all of my strings shoudl be using ASCII-compatible characters.